# Symfony3: Database and Entity settings: Neither property … nor method …nor method … exists in class

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

I know there are similar questions, but none of the solutions work for Symfony 3.x.

So I have three entities, User, Role and Permission. User has Roles (ManyToMany) and Permissions (also ManyToMany). And then I have a form, and while Permissions work fine, Roles do not.

The only difference I can see, is that a function returning roles isn't called getRoles as it should(?), because a function with this name has to return array of strings (not array of role entities) to meet expectations of the AdvancedUserInterface, that is why another function (getRoleEntities) returns $this->roles, but I believe I reflected it while building a form.

Here is a shortened version of the User entity class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable {
    //id, username, personalname, password, email and isactive ommited

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Permission", cascade = {"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_permission")
     */
    private $permissions;//this works

    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Role", cascade = {"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role")
     */
    private $roles;//this doesn't work


    public function __construct() {
        $this->permission = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //irrelevant getters/setters ommited

    /**
     * Add Permission
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Permission $userPermission
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addPermission(\AppBundle\Entity\Permission $userPermission) {
        $this->permissions[] = $userPermission;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove Permission
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Permission $userPermission
     */
    public function removePermission(\AppBundle\Entity\Permission $userPermission) {
        $this->permissions->removeElement($userPermission);
    }

    /**
     * Get Permissions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getPermissions() {
        return $this->permissions;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////
    //roles

    /**
     * Add role
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Role $role
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function addRoleEntity(\AppBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
        $this->roles[] = $role;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove role
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Role $role
     */
    public function removeRoleEntity(\AppBundle\Entity\Role $role) {
        $this->roleRoles->removeElement($role);
    }

    /**
     * I know this one should simply return $this->roles, but it has to return array of strings to meet expectations of the AdvancedUserInterface, that is why another function (getRoleEntities) returns $this->roles
     * @return array
     */
    public function getRoles() {
        $ret_val = array();
        $roles = $this->getRoleEntities();

        if ($roles) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                $ret_val[] = $role->getRoleName();
            }
        }
        return $ret_val;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     */
    public function getRoleEntities() {
        return $this->roles;
    }

}
```

And here is how I build a form:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->find('AppBundle:User',1);//just for testing


    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
        ->add('personal_name', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Imię i nazwisko: '))
        ->add('is_active', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Active: ','required' => false))
        ->add('permissions',  \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class , array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Permission', 
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true
        ))
        ->add('roleEntities',  \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class , array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Role', 
        ))

        ->add('save', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'))
        ->getForm();
```

And when I'm opening a page I get this exception:

> Neither the property "roleEntities" nor one of the methods
>   "addRoleEntity()"/"removeRoleEntity()", "setRoleEntities()",
>   "roleEntities()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access
>   in class "AppBundle\Entity\User".

ps. I tagged this "symfony2", because AFAIK there are no big differences between 2.9 and 3.0

Comment: Name your field `roles` instead of `roleEntities`.

Comment: But it is named "roles", it's just that the getter is named "getRolesEntieties" - this is necessary, because a function named "getRoles" has to return an array of strings (not array of role entities) to meet expectations of the AdvancedUserInterface which I implement,

Comment: In form you must name it `roles` or set `mapped=false` if you have no field named `roleEntity`.

Comment: @malcom - I can see from your profile, that you know a lot about Symfony, but I think you haven't read the entire question :(

I can't do mapped=false, because I DO have a relation between Users and Roles in database, ManyToMany. And I do want it to be edited (modified).

But OK, I changed the field in form to "roles" and made the property in entity class public hoping that Symfony will pick this up, instead of trying to call the getRoles function in entity class (since it must return array of string not the $roles property).

And now I have this exception:

Comment: "Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/analytics/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 605 and defined"

Precisely, UnitOfWork ->computeChangeSet function tries to pass the Role entity object instead of an array to ArrayCollection::__construct()

Why is that?

Please help me, I've been working on this for the last 6 hours... :(

Comment: I haven't read the entire question, but I want to inform you that you must name form field exactly what you named it in class property. Thats way it's mapped correctly. I don't know why you use roles as standalone entity (are you drupal developer before?), and I don't know ORM (for years I use only mongodb), so I cannot help you with ORM mappings. Just simply if you want to add form field, the name must be the same as class property, otherwise you must set `mapped = false`.

Comment: OK, thanks, although I still have an error, this time it's a different one, hence if you add your comment as answer I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

OK, fortunately guys from #Symfony irc, helped me, there are a few issues there:

1. functions like addRoleEntity should rather be called after the variable, e.g. addRole
2. Like @malcom mentioned, while building the form, instead of:

   ->add('roleEntities',  \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class , array(
               'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Role',

It should be:

```
->add('roles', \Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType::class , array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Role', 
            'multiple' => true,
```

)

Because this is how the variable is named. Plus, since this is ManyToMany I also added 'multiple' => true, otherwise it did save, but incorectly loaded this information.

3.It went further, and a new error appeared: Can not read the choices from the choice list.

I changed the body of the getRoles method to:

```
return $this->roles->toArray();
```

And it worked.

The last idea is mine, not from the IRC, I'm saying this, because I don't like this solution. If it is a bad solution, then it's my fault.